# Sorting multiple columns using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have to sort columns in Excel on their values.

I worked out the following procedure:

```
With calcCalculations

    With .Sort    
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("BR2:BR5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("BV2:BV5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("CA2:CA5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("CD2:CD5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .SetRange Range("BR:CD")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = True
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    End With

End with
```

The procedure does not error out, but it is not sorting my data.

Comment: At the end, **.apply** otherwise you only set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user3514930 said: You're missing the `.Apply` before the `End With`

Answer (score 1):

```
                With calcCalculations

With .Sort

.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("BR2:BR5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("BV2:BV5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("CA2:CA5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("CD2:CD5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

         .SetRange Range("BR:CD")
         .Header = xlYes
         .MatchCase = True
         .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
         .SortMethod = xlPinYin
         .Apply
        End With

End with
```

As the other users said.